# Rigging multiple 2d layered planes for feathers

Tags: rigging

So I'm trying to rig layered planes to use as layers of feathers and cant get the armature to fully influence the mesh and end up with horrible clipping issues. even when the bone says it has 100% weight it still leaves the mesh behind a little. I've tried with them all combined then each layer separately but had the same issue. I also tried subdividing but that didn't help either.

[image]

[image: the issue]

[image: issue part 2]